# Gun in Fortnite jamming?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

So i’ve Been playing Fortnite and I’m an advid fan of the Scar, whenever I come across one I always switch out what I have for it. But all the sudden last night it started shooting random spurts of bullets and sometimes just not shooting. Occasionally it will work normally but other times not. I’m occasionally experiencing this with other guns, but most often the Scar. What’s going on?!

Comment: Was this mobile, pc, or console?

Comment: I read something about having "Building Pro" enabled causes this.  Do you have an option like that enabled?

Comment: Could this be just a lag?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This may be many things. Your mouse may be malfunctioning or broken, as that would explain random shooting. This may also be lag, or from Fortnite itself with the massive influx of players joining and playing the game. I suggest seeing if this has been happening on other games, and if not, seeing your ping and FPS in Fortnite.

Comment: Turns out another guy had the same problem online, with the same gun even!